# How to get IP address of logged in user using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client, httpclient, webclient

I have this small snippet of code which allows me to retrieve the public IP address

```
 $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            alert(response.ip);
        }, "jsonp");
```

I would like to be able to get the actual IP v 4 address of the machine the client is using much similar to that displayed in command prompt after entering the ipconfig command

Comment: Why would you need to know that? - Don't forget the address you get may not be routeable...

Comment: Iam not sure if you are trying to be rude or if your question is genuine ? we have device sensors in different networks and locations and we would like to log as much info to the database

Comment: For a LAN environment, could you not determine the client IP from the server side? Can you rely on your devices/sensors on supporting the relevent HTML5 modules that allow you to do this?